# Effect of excluding <!DOCTYPE>?

Tags: html, xml, dhtml

What does `<!DOCTYPE>` describe other than the version of HTML being used and if excluded what are the consequences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doctype basically tells the browser that the page is compliant with HTML standards. Omitting the doctype can make certain browsers (chief among them, Internet Explorer) go haywire and fall back to a "Quirks Mode", in which HTML elements aren't rendered to standard.

> In the Quirks mode the browsers violate contemporary Web format specifications in order to avoid “breaking” pages authored according to practices that were prevalent in the late 1990s. Different browsers implement different quirks. In Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8 and 9, the Quirks mode is effectively frozen IE 5.5. In other browsers, the Quirks mode is a handful of deviations from the Almost Standards mode.

Further reading: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Answer (score 2):

if there is no  presented. IE will use "Quirks mode" by default. (You can you F12 in IE to see the current mode.)

And in quirks mode many css rule is different.

Here's an article about [Quirks mode and strict mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is not just one type of HTML, there are actually many: HTML 4.01 Strict, HTML 4.01 Transitional, XHTML 1.0 Strict, and many more. All these types of HTML are defined in their respective W3C specifications

Why specify a doctype? Because it defines which version of (X)HTML your document is actually using, and this is a critical piece of information needed by some tools processing the document.

For example, specifying the doctype of your document allows you to use tools such as the [Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check the syntax of your (X)HTML. Such tools won't be able to work if they do not know what kind of document you are using.

Answer (score 0):

For knowing about the usage and importanse of DOCTYPE see the link [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

Always add the  declaration to your HTML documents, so that the browser knows what type of document to expect.